# 8 queens puzzle conflict checking

Tags: c++, conflict, n-queens

I recently read up about the 8 queens problem and tried to solve it myself, in C++. I made a class called eq.h, an implementation file called eq.cpp, and a main.cpp.

The thing that I'm not sure about is, how do I check for row, column, and diagonal conflicts? What I'm thinking is, to use a nested for loop for conflict checking. How can that be applied? I've created a valid() function for that purpose. Below is what I've got so far.

1) eq.h

```
#ifndef 8QUEEN_H
#define 8QUEEN_H

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class 8queen
{
        public:
            8queen();
            ~8queen();
            int solve();//solve problem using next_permutation
            void display();

        private:
            bool valid();
            int queens[8]; //array to store 8 integers that represent 8 queens
};
#endif
```

2) eq.cpp

```
#include "eq.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

8queen::8queen()
{
    for(int i=0;i<0;i++)
    {
        queens[i]=i;
    }
}

8queen::~8queen()
{

}

//using next_perm, return all possible positions of the queens
int 8queen::solve()
{
    int count=0;
    do{
        if(valid())
        {
            count++;
            display();
        }
    }
    while(next_permutation(queens,queens+8));
    return count;
}

//display the positions of the queens
void 8queen::display()
{
    for(int i=0; i<0;i++)
    {
        cout<<queens[i]<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
    }
}

//check if position is valid or not
bool 8queen::valid()
{
    return true;
}
```

3) main.cpp

```
#include "eq.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    8queen object;


    cout<<object.solve()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: hm, diagonal conflicts are more difficult than horizontal and vertical. for horizontal and vertical conflicts you could store an array or set of 1 to 8 rows/columns that queens take. I think that you can use the same technique for diagonals conflicts too. think about it ;)

Comment: Identifiers cannot start with numerals. Change `8queen` to `queen8` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Ok

Suppose you have chess grid.

For horizontal and vertical conflicts you can use `set` that store `i` and `j` (row and column) of queen's position. If another queen have the same `i` or `j` - conflict.

Keynote:

`SET`
`row_set contains? (i) - conflict`

`column_set contains? (j) - conflict`

Diagonal conflicts  (from left corner to right corner)
More complex case.
Suppose that you have queen on `(1,1)` and want to put new queen on `(8,8)`
So this situation can be conflict. Sure.
It happens if difference value `(j - i)` are the same.

Suppose that you have queen on `(1,7)` and want to put queen on `(2,8)`
Again, difference value `(j - i)` are the same here.

Diagonal conflicts (from right corner to left corner)

Suppose that you have queen on `(8,1)` and want to put new queen on `(1,8)`
Conflict.
It happens if sum value `(j + i)` are the same.
Suppose that you have queen on `(1,2)` and want to put new queen on `(2,1)`
Conflict!
It happens cause sum value the same `(j + i)`

Keynote:

`SET`
`left_to_right_set contains? (j - i)` - conflict
`right_to_left_set contains? (j + i)` - conflict

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code instead. `c[0][i]` contains # of queens in one row, `c[1][i]` contains # of queens in one column, `d[0][i]` contains # of queens for a reverse diagonals, `d[1][i]` contains # of queens for a main diagonals. Edit it to treat 8x8 grid instead of 4x4 grid.

```
int c[2][4] = {}, d[2][7] = {};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        char x;
        cin >> x;
        if (x != 'x') continue;
        ++c[0][i], ++c[1][j];
        ++d[0][i + j], ++d[1][i + (3 - j)];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    if (c[0][i] > 1 || c[1][i] > 1)
        return true;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    if (d[0][i] > 1 || d[1][i] > 1)
        return true;
return false;
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/zXRTkz)

Comment: why not use sets? this is more simple to understand

Comment: @gaussblurinc Why don't I use less performant and more complex solution, you mean?